# Linux tools to inspect Windows DLLs

Tags: windows, linux, dll, inspection

I have to debug a problem with Windows DLLs, but I'm running Linux exclusively, so I was wondering whether there are (preferably command-line) tools to inspect Windows DLLs under Linux. What I'm looking for is mainly the list of exported symbols.

Comment: Can't you run some Windows in an VM (e.g. Qemu), or use Wine ?

Comment: Just curious - if you're debugging a Windows DLL under Linux, how are you executing it?

Comment: @EricSmith I'm not trying to execute it, I just wanted to check for the existenace of some symbols.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Which program can I use under Wine to get a list of exported symbols from a DLL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked if Dependency Walker will work under wine?

http://dependencywalker.com/

(just a WAG)

How to use it on the command line (Run it from the same directory as the DLL):

```
wine /full/path/to/depends.exe /c /of:output.txt dynamic-library.dll
```

Comment: gives me `err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\tmp\\depends22_x64\\depends.exe") not found`, even though this very dll is active

Answer (score 14):

Use "winedump -j export file.dll"
winedump is part of Wine

Homepage:
https://www.winehq.org/docs/winedump

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/knik0/peinfo

works nicely. Tested with several Windows DLLs 64 bits